# How to properly write the LPPL 1.3c license preamble?

Tags: licensing

I recently uploaded a few packages to CTAN, and for the license in the preamble I copied the following text from the documentation of `dtxtut`:

```
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
%% version 1.3 of this license or (at your option) any later
%% version. The latest version of this license is in:
%%
%% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%%
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of
%% LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
```

However the CTAN staff kindly reminded me in the emails that this is only for **LPPL 1.3**, not **1.3c**. I then searched on the Internet, only to find the same text on [the page for LPPL 1.3c](https://www.latex-project.org/lppl/lppl-1-3c/#whether-and-how-to-distribute-works-under-this-license).

I wonder what is the correct way to use LPPL 1.3**c**?

Comment: Perhaps see how Joseph does it in `siunitx`, see https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.dtx, he as far as I can see it just refers to 1.3c instead of 1.3. If you look in http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt it explicitly states that this is revision 1.3c, so I'm thinking that this is what the CTAN staff is refering to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LPPL had a few very minor corrections at the level of typographic changes between 1.3 and the current 1.3c. As there is no substantive change between these versions, CTAN do not log them separately (contrast earlier versions of the LPPL, which are tracked). There is really no reason to pick v1.3 (or v1.3a or v1.3b) over v1.3c, so it is best to simply adapt your text to point to the latest version.